# QuickBooks API - query SalesItemLineDetail

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am creating a Invoice in QB with PHP API. `DetailType` was required so that I add `$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');` as in the example from https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_add.php#L21.

Then it sets

```
$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('8');
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(20 * 0.516129);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1.00000);
```

Note that `setItemRef` is hard coded to 8.

Now I want to search a `SalesItemLineDetail` by name and get the ref.

Just to see whether I can get all I tried,

```
$pref->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM SalesItemLineDetail");
```

Normally we do `query` with a service. in my case which is `$pref`.

I tried, `InvoiceService`, `SalesOrderService`, `PreferencesService`, `ItemService` but I am not getting any result.

Please help me to find a `Product / Service` in a `Invoice` by name and get its ref.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any help? Any suggestion? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out!

What we need is the `ItemService`. This is how I did it.

```
$ItemService = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Item();
$response = $ItemService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Item where Name = 'Services'");
```

from the `$response` I get the ID. So that I do not need to hard code any ID.

Hope this might help anyone having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't search by `SalesLineItemDetail`. Intuit does not support it.

If you are trying to just find an `ItemRef` within an existing invoice, you can query for the invoice first:

```
$list = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT *, Line.* FROM Invoice WHERE Id = '5' ");
```

And then loop through the line items to get the data:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_lines; $i++)
{
    $Line = $Invoice->getLine($i);

    if ($Line->getDetailType() == 'SalesItemLineDetail')
    {
        $Detail = $Line->getSalesItemLineDetail();
        $item_id = $Detail->getItemRef();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a Invoice line without specifying `$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');`? Please help!

Comment: You must specify a `DetailType` (though it doesn't necessarily have to be `SalesItemLineDetail`). Have you read the documentation?